# How do I parse/read this XML file in JSP

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xml-parsing

I have following XML files below which I am trying to read from JSP using the tutorial on http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-read-xml-file/:

**XML FILE 1:**

```
<root>

  <data v="1.0">

    <cellimage counter="0" cash_filename="C:\Temp\_TempFolder\39d437f08cc302876a70a0f91b137991_h.jpg" width="94" height="141" />

    <cellimage counter="1" cash_filename="C:\Temp\_TempFolder\39d437f08cc302876a70a0f91b137991_h.jpg" width="94" height="141" />

  </data>

</root>
```

**XML FILE 2**

```
<people>
  <person>
    <name>Joe</name>
    <age>30</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Rob</name>
    <age>29</age>
  </person>
</people>
```

XML file 1 above throws an error on following line but 2nd XML file works just fine. Can someone please tell me how I can make the XML file 1 to work?

```
 String dateTagValue=dateElements.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
```

Error stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /html/archivedetails/view.jsp at line 33

30:     for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
31:         NodeList nameNlc = doc.getElementsByTagName("counter");
32:         Element nameElements = (Element) nameNlc.item(i);
33:         String nameTagValue = nameElements.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
34: 
35:         out.println("name :" + nameTagValue + "<br>");
36:     }


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:323)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:105)
    ... 167 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.html.archivedetails.view_jsp._jspService(view_jsp.java:152)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    ... 182 more
```

Comment: The answer depends on how how you obtained a value for `dateElements`.  Also, you haven't told us what error occurs, nor have you provided a stack trace. Without more of the code and a stack trace, nobody can help you.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I have added the stacktrace now to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is in

```
String nameTagValue = nameElements.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
```

So either `nameElements` is null or it has no child nodes (`getChildNodes()` returns null).

The code is highly suspicious because you are looping over `nl`, but then using the index to access elements of `nameNlc` which may or may not have the same number of elements.  Also, you're looking for elements named `<counter>`, which don't appear in either sample.

There's a serious disconnect between the error message and what you're showing, and I suspect you need to take a close look at what you're doing.  There are probably other inconsistencies as well.

I realize this is borderline as an answer (may have been better as a comment) but it's too long for a comment and, given the inconsistencies in your post, is probably the best you can hope for.